# How to call a function from html button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to call a function from a button in the html body when onclick. This function sends the id to a php for processing some information. 
The problem is that when I press the button, it is not calling the function. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

This is the code,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Carrental</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <script>
             function delete(id){

                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var available = this.responseText;
                      }
                  };
                xhttp.open("GET", "add_delete_session.php?action=delete&id="+id, true);
                xhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="delete(9)">Erase</button>
    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`delete` is an operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). You cannot use it as the name of a variable.

Rename the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `delete` to another name function , `delete` is an operator , you can see the list of operators here : [Expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

```
function ajaxCall(id){

                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        var available = this.responseText;
                      }
                  };
                xhttp.open("GET", "add_delete_session.php?action=delete&id="+id, true);
                xhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="ajaxCall(9)">Erase</button>
    </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cant call the function delete. Just Rename it :)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is delete is operator in JavaScript

The JavaScript delete operator removes a property from an object; if no more references to the same property are held, it is eventually released automatically.

So your code try to delete the object or element mentioned after it and is not calling method you wrote.

As per example in [@Pluto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13394585/pluto) https://stackoverflow.com/a/62086635/124891
You have to rename the method and call it.